# Использование DateTime.Substract в LINQ выбивает ошибку

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

По задумке из БД должны приходить сотрудники у которых разница между текущей датой и датой старта больше 180 дней. Вот вроде и лямбду написал, но при выполнении выбивает ошибку:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .Where(e => !(e.IsDeleted) && e.WorkEndDate == null && DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(e.WorkStartDate).Days > 180)' could not be translated.

Сам код:

```cs
var targetEmployees = await _dbContext.Employees
                    .Where(emp => !emp.IsDeleted && emp.WorkEndDate == null && (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(emp.WorkStartDate).Days > 180))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно ввести дополнительную переменную с посчитанным значением и использовать её в запросе.

```
var dt = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-180);

var targetEmployees = await _dbContext.Employees
    .Where(emp => !emp.IsDeleted && emp.WorkEndDate == null && dt > emp.WorkStartDate)
```

---

Есть специальные классы с набором функций, которые можно использовать в запросах. [DbFunctions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions?view=efcore-5.0) в EF Core. [SqlFunctions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlfunctions?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) в EF 6.

Answer (score 2):

Всем спасибо, получилось сделать элегантное решение:

```
var targetEmployees = _dbContext.Employees
                .Where(emp => !emp.IsDeleted && emp.WorkEndDate == null && (EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(DateTime.UtcNow, emp.WorkStartDate) > 180))
```

Comment: Это хорошее решение. Однако, отмечу, что EF.Functions должны образом работают только с Sql Server. Провайдеры других СУБД могут не реализовывать их.

Comment: Запрос использующий DateDiffDay может плохо оптимизироваться.

Answer (score -3):

```
Решил следующим образом:
var targetEmployees = await _dbContext.Employees
                    .Where(emp => !emp.IsDeleted && emp.WorkEndDate == null)
    .AsAnumerable()   //создаём локалькую коллекцию, чтобы не нужно было транслировать условие в SQL
    .Where(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(emp.WorkStartDate).Days > 180));
```

Comment: Это может оказаться очень неэффективно, т. к. большой объём данных будет загружен из БД на клиента.